# User Sessions in an oauth2 django app

Tags: python, django, session

I use django, django rest framework and ember.js; my entire application thereforce communicates via ajax.

Authentication is done via oauth2 and a token is send in the headers within every request.

Everythings nice and shiny but file downloads.

At one point users can download a pdf and I don't know how to apply authentication there - because on the file download I cannot send and headers, it's just a link.

I thought of adding SessionAuthentication to that particular rest api call, but the session always flags the incoming user as anyonymous.

How can I force django to create a session on top of the oauth2 token flow?

I tried `login(request, user)`, but it somehow does not kick in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with signed tickets, e.g. i send back a token, that is able to bypass auth for a defined timeframe. Therefore the ajax app can first request the token and then fire again a standard get request with the token attached.

Here's the basic idea, that I mixin to views:

```
class DownloadableMixin():
    """
    Manages a ticket response, where a ticket is a signed response that gives a user limited access to a resource
    for a time frame of 5 secs.

    Therefore, file downloads can request a ticket for a resource and gets a ticket in the response that he can
    use for non-ajax file-downloads.
    """

    MAX_AGE = 5

    def check_ticket(self, request):
        signer = TimestampSigner()
        try:
            unsigned_ticket = signer.unsign(request.QUERY_PARAMS['ticket'], max_age=self.__class__.MAX_AGE)
        except SignatureExpired:
            return False
        except BadSignature:
            return False

        if self.get_requested_file_name() == unsigned_ticket:
            return True
        return False

    def get_ticket(self):
        signer = TimestampSigner()
        return signer.sign(self.get_requested_file_name())

    def has_ticket(self, request):
        return 'ticket' in request.QUERY_PARAMS

    def requires_ticket(self, request):
        return 'download' in request.QUERY_PARAMS

    def get_requested_file_name(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('Extending classes must define the requested file name.')
```